# Regex matches text, but c# doesn't find a match

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching, match

I'm trying to match a Regex to a date in a text file that I've created from a PDF. The Regex matches when I build it in Regexhero, but when de-bugging I found that c# is not finding a match at all.

Any thoughts as to why this would happen?

I can provide some code if that would help, but all of my other regex's are matching and the code is very robust, involving many different classes, public variables, and functions. It would take some time to make readable.

(using vs 2012 pro in c# console application)
(Regex confirmed with regexhero)

**Regex:**
 *?((Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) *\d{1,2}, *\d{4})\n.*?\n. *?GEORGIA POWER COMPANY

**text file snippet:**

```
                                                      Dec 26, 2012

GEORGIA POWER COMPANY
BIN #19999
21141 Ralph McGuiver Blvd.
Atlanta, GA 30308-3374




                         GI LANDING LLC
                         Customer***
                         PO BOX 1234
                         LOGAN UT 84323





                                                                                                                              Please Pay By                                Jan 10, 2013
                                                           Customer Name                                   Account Number     Total Due                                              $ 61.91
                                                           IV LANDING LLC                      19380-29341


             Service Address                                                                                 Service Period   Contact Us 24 hours a day, 7 days a week
             900 GI LANDING DR                                                        Nov 26, 2012 - Dec 25, 2012
             HSE A                                                                                                                      georgiapower.com
                                                                                                                                           Account Number             Web Access Code
             Billing Summary
                                                                                                                                           135130-530141              845089
             Previous Bill Amount                                                                                  $ 63.34                 Customer Service           Power Outage Reporting
             Payment Received On 12/06/12                                 Thank You!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one that worked. All of your responses worked in Expresso and regexhero, howver, my particular console app only liked this one for some reason.
Thanks for the responses.

Correct Regex:
"\s*((Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s\d{1,2},\s\d{4})\s*G"

Answer (score 1):

There are a few errors in your pattern. First of all, the first character, '*', is not applied to any character previously and results in an exception thrown by the regex. Furthermore, the `\n.?\n. *?` segment assumes that the only line separator is `\n`, while in our case there are also `\r` characters.

Your correct pattern should be, approximately:

```
\s*?((Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s\d{1,2},\s\d{4})[\r\n]*GEORGIA POWER COMPANY
```

You may adapt it to make it more restrictive, however.

Example of how to use it:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\s*?((Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s\d{1,2},\s\d{4})[\r\n]*GEORGIA POWER COMPANY");
var input = @"your input here";
var match = regex.Match(input);
if (match.Success) { /*Operate*/ }
```

Comment: My regex should have contained a " " before the "*". When pastening it into here I guess it removed the space. however, your regex is much better. But I am still getting an error: "ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled"..?

Comment: It works correctly for me. I've edited my post with an example of how to use it.

Comment: I ended up using most of the logic behind your regex. It just ended up getting stuck on the "[\r\n]*".

Comment: Thanks for all of the help. I've posted what I ended up using as an answer to my own question. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

The regex you are using is incorrect. I checked it with Expresso.

The following regex will match the date that you require. The date can be extracted from the group **DATE**.

```
(?<DATE>(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)?\s+\d{1,2},\s+\d{4})\s+GEORGIA POWER COMPANY
```